# PostgreSQL window function issue: asking for GROUP BY

Tags: postgresql

I have a table storing pipes together with dates and cities. I need to calculate the pipes' length sum and percentage by city and installing year.

Here is the result I'm looking for:

```
  city   |   install_year   |   length   |   percentage
---------+------------------+------------+---------------
  A      |  2014            |  90        |   32.14
  A      |  2013            |  70        |   25.00
  A      |  2012            |  120       |   42.85
  B      |  2010            |  325       |   100.0
```

I build a test table with this script:

```
CREATE TABLE pipes (gid serial NOT NULL, city TEXT, install_year INTEGER, length INTEGER) ;

INSERT INTO pipes (city, install_year, length) VALUES ('A',2014,10), ('A',2014,20), ('A',2014,60), ('A',2013,70), ('A',2012,120), ('B',2010,325) ;
```

To achieve my query, I use a window function to calculate pipes' length sum for each town, as follow:

```
SELECT
  city,
  install_year,
  sum(length) AS length,
  (sum(length)*100 / sum(length) OVER (PARTITION BY city)) AS percentage

FROM pipes 

GROUP BY city, install_year 

ORDER BY city, install_year DESC ;
```

I get an error message asking me to add column 'length' to the GROUP BY clause, which does not give the same result at all (and I do not want to group by length, it would be pointless).

Anyone has an idea to do it differently? I'm afraid I will have to use a temporary table with a `WITH mytable AS (...) SELECT ...`.

Comment: `sum(length)*100 / sum(length)` is always 100 so that's probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window functions apply after group by, you should always use the `WINDOW` keyword to remember this.

You were close, you only need to sum the sums to get the total by city.

```
SELECT
  city,
  install_year,
  sum(length) AS length,
  sum(sum(length)) OVER w AS total_by_city,
  (sum(length) * 100) / (sum(sum(length)) OVER w) AS percentage
FROM pipes
GROUP BY city, install_year
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY city )
ORDER BY city, install_year DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had found another solution in the meantime (see next answer). Can you tell me your opinion about this?

Comment: Clever solution, but I think it's a bit less efficient because using a group by reduce the amount of rows that needs to be processed by window functions. Totally depend on your real world row number, a group by could kill performances too. I find your solution a bit harder to read too, the distinct doesn't help to understand what the query does at first glance, as in my solution, only the `percentage` needs some more thinking and the rest of the query is quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

I had found this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  city,
  install_year,
  sum(length) OVER (PARTITION BY city, install_year) AS length,
  sum(length) OVER (PARTITION BY city, install_year)*100 / sum(length) OVER (PARTITION BY city) AS percentage

FROM pipes

ORDER BY city, install_year DESC ;
```